Best way to convert free text column to all lowercase in pandas dataframe?
If I have a pandas dataframe like:
import pandas as pd

columns = ['machine_num', 'comments']
data = [(232323, 'BOOMER COMMENT HERE'), 
        (123456, 'GenX comment here'),
        (121212, 'ZoOmEr CoMmEnT hErE')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
# df.at['Total marks', 'Marks'] = df['Marks'].sum()

df




machine_num
description




232323
BOOMER COMMENT HERE


123456
GenX comment here


121212
ZoOmEr CoMmEnT hErE



What's the most performant way to convert the free text column to all lowercase strings in Python? I'm prepping the data for NLP later.
i.e., so it looks something like this:



machine_num
description




232323
boomer comment here


123456
genx comment here


121212
zoomer comment here



I tried this, which runs fine with with a test df...
df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.lower() #convert to all lowercase
df

...but the ultimate goal is to run on millions of rows.

I don't do any NLP myself, but I would expect that the libraries don't require everything to be lower-cased first.

There is no magic, working with strings is slow. You're already using the fastest approach in pandas

@mozway IIRC, if you can guarantee there are no nulls, then <column>.apply(str.lower) is slightly faster. Anyway, I'd want to %%timeit to see if it makes much difference.

My test suggested a fraction of second for 1M rows. Is this really a problem?

You may use a loop to make it lowercase for local purpose. For global sense, divide your datasets into multiple parts, then run all the small files parallely. It would reduce the time. At last, aggregate all the files together.

Thanks @mozway! This isn't a problem yet, but I just wanted to make sure I was building performant code from the beginning as this will be used across many pipelines.
